# Edited question with more details

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Getting xml elements that contains comma delimited string - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785233/getting-xml-elements-that-contains-comma-delimited-string-jquery)

I've modified the question with XML and more information, please can it be opened.

Comment: Presumably the code you've posted doesn't do what you want, so what *does* it do? Show the expected and actual outputs to clarify the specific problem.

Comment: I am sorry but imho this is still unclear. I am working with xslt since a while, and I know jquery quite well, but I can not decode your question. I can not see your mind, I can not see your computer, I can only see what you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

No, the question in *the current state* can't be re-opened.

Main reason - it is missing a question - it has *some* XML and *some* JavaScript posted, but does not explain what exactly is the problem with your script - does it have syntax errors you can't understand, does it fail with an exception, don't find all nodes? Note that comments *are not* part of the question - you need to edit them into the question to count.

It also does not look like XML is related to the text in the body of the question: "where country contains ('1234', '5678') and Business module contains ('123:0', '456:0')" - there is nothing that looks like  "country" or "business module" in the XML. It is possible that you pasted wrong XML or some particular nodes in XML have meaning for you but that meaning is unclear for readers of the post.

If I would try to make the question re-openable I'd

- edit XML to be much smaller and fit on screen without scrolling. It looks like most attributes there are not needed
- make sure all names align across text, data and code sample - if something is called "country" in the text it should be called the same in data and code.
- review code and make sure it contains only parts related to the question and code works on the data shown it the post (and check if it meets [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guideline if I feel I may be missing something)

Comment: I've modified the whole edit and hopefully now it makes sense.